# How the exported csv file from DB2 can include the content of XML

Tags: sql, xml, csv, db2

I am trying to export a table with XMLType field from DB2 to a csv.

And I found that inside the csv file, the relational field in table can output the values correctly.

But the value of the XMLType field is a pointer to an exported XML file.

The csv file content:

`1349714,,2,<XDS FIL='result.csv.001.xml' OFF='0' LEN='7013' />,2014-01-22-16.38.58.314000`

You can see that the 4th field value is a pointer to a XML file.

May I know the command to include the XML content when exporting to a csv file in DB2??

For now, I'm using this cmd to do export:

```
EXPORT TO result.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL SELECT col1, col2, coln FROM dbtable;
```

Thanks Buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert XML to a character data type, e.g. using `XMLSERIALIZE(yourxmlcolumn AS VARCHAR(32672))`. Keep in mind that both the `VARCHAR` data type and the delimited export format have limitations on the value length (32672 and 32700 bytes respectively), so if your serialized XML fragment is longer than that it will be truncated.

Comment: Thanks your solution. But I found that the XML data content are in wrong encoding in the csv file. May I know how can I export the correct encoding of XML content? thanks

Comment: Will it be the problem of VARCHAR?

Comment: I checked that the encoding is correct with the encoding UTF-8 for standard. That's only my problem to use excel to view such csv file. I used notepad++ or EditPlus to view it and get correct result, thanks!!!!